# How to Push data from xlsx excel sheet to sqlalchemy database using Transpose and pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to push the excel file by using `to_sql` function and using data frame after transpose the `dataframe`...

and this is my code looks like

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sqlalchemy

# MySQL Connection
MYSQL_USER = 'xxxxx'
MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxx'
MYSQL_HOST_IP = '127.0.0.1'
MYSQL_PORT = 3306
MYSQL_DATABASE = 'xlsx_test_db'

# connect db
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://' + MYSQL_USER + ':' + MYSQL_PASSWORD + '@' + MYSQL_HOST_IP + ':' + str(
    MYSQL_PORT) + '/' + MYSQL_DATABASE, echo=False)
engine.connect()


mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

raw_lte = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027.xlsx', sheet_name='raw_4G')

dft = raw_lte.T
dft.columns = dft.iloc[0]
dft = dft.iloc[1:]

# reading and insert one file at a time
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    # only process excels files
    file_basename, extension = file.split('.')
    if extension == 'xlsx':
        dft.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

and this the error

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 507, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'index' used in key specification without a key length

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/automateDB/swap.py", line 36, in <module>
    dft.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2532, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 460, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1173, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 585, in create
    self._execute_create()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 569, in _execute_create
    self.table.create()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 778, in create
    checkfirst=checkfirst)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1940, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1549, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 796, in visit_table
    self.traverse_single(index)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 823, in visit_index
    self.connection.execute(CreateIndex(index))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 68, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1009, in _execute_ddl
    compiled
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 507, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'index' used in key specification without a key length [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX `ix_mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027_index` ON `mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027` (`index`)'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I think there's a problem with the excel format, but I don't know to solve this issue

Note:
I tried to use this

`raw_4G.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace')`

insted of

`dft.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace')`

It works but it gives me error in the run time with this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/automateDB/swap.py", line 34, in <module>
    file_basename, extension = file.split('.')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: add `index=False` if you aren't using it `dft.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)`

Comment: @Datanovice thanks a lot for your support the error is gone but I found another error with the `Maria DB` I think I have a problem with the format of columns.... columns name looks like this `Voice_SetupFailRate_4G(%)`, do you have any idea to solve this?.... thanks a lot for your help

Comment: for starters your code is not correct, you are looping through your directory and adding the same file to the db, which you called above (unless it's just pseudo code?) I'm not sure about the column names, is it hte same in the target database?

Comment: @Datanovice thanks a lot for your support first I am putting the same file, as I'll use watch dog library... as to watch the path if there's any update with the excel file... just take the excel file and replace with old one and put it in the data base.........
Now I am facing a new problem, I just need help with some Regular expressions to solve.... Please follow my next question

Comment: sounds like an interesting project! i saw your questionw as answered, good luck :)

Comment: @Datanovice  thanks a lot :)... but I am facing w new problem with an error ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near` :) ... because of columns name contains bracket and special character so am trying to solve this now :)